# Disable horizontal scroll bar in GWT-RichTextArea in IE

Tags: gwt

How can i disable horizontal scroll bar in gwt-richtextarea

I applied overflow-x:hidden and is working fine on firefox but not working on IE

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: Surprisingly I tried below code but, as you (@Ashwin Hegde) told working only in firefox. Not in chrome also.

public void onModuleLoad() {
  RichTextArea area = new RichTextArea();
area.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("overflowY", "hidden");
  RootPanel.get().add(area);
 }

Comment: Which IE you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RichTextArea` uses an `iframe` to embed the editable html document.

When you set styles to the rich area, you are setting them to the `iframe` element, but in your case you have to set styles to the `body` element of the `iframe #document`.

The problem here is how to get the content document of the iframe, you have to use jsni, or use a 3party library like [gwt-query](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/).

This works with qQuery:

```java
  import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;

    RichTextArea area = new RichTextArea();
    RootPanel.get().add(area);

    $(area).contents().find("body").css($$("overflow-x: hidden"));
```

Another issue is that the creation of the editable document in the iframe is delayed in gwt. So it is safer if you delay the setting of styles, using a `Timer`.

With gquery you can use the `delay()` method

```java
  $(area).delay(100, 
    lazy().contents().find("body").css($$("overflow-x: hidden")).done()
  );
```